# numpy: Print array enforcing scientific notation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, printing, scientific-notation

I need to print a numpy array with scientific notation regardless of the value of the components of the array.

To my knowledge, `numpy.format_float_scientific` acts only on scalars and returns error if applied to vectors - therefore, I need an alternative.

Thank you,
Davide

Answer (score 0):

I would do smth like this:

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'all':np.format_float_scientific})
print(np.arange(5))
```

output:

```
[0.e+00 1.e+00 2.e+00 3.e+00 4.e+00]
```